# Do light color codes work across all distros and terminals?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, colors, brightness

I use `\033[1;34m` for light blue. I am using Debian and Putty and it works for me.

However, I've heard that it may not work for all users (using different distros and terminals). Is that true? Do they have different codes for light colors?

I want to add an option to the configuration file of my program to display light colors instead of regular ones.

Comment: If your end goal is to always have light blue, you might be out of luck -- I've seen terminal emulators that let me configure the 16 (IIRC) available colors freely.

Comment: Distros, yes. Terminals, probably not.

Comment: I want to add an option to the configuration file of my program to display light colors instead of regular ones.

Comment: Related - [What is the difference between tput's 'setf' and 'setaf'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139018/what-is-the-difference-between-tputs-setf-and-setaf/158410#158410)

Comment: No, this depends on the terminal implementation, and is well-known.  See the xterm FAQ for instance [Aren't bright colors the same as bold?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bold_vs_16colors).